# Flutter Test Mock GraphQL mutation doesn't find stub

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, graphql, mocking

I'm using mockito and graphql packages in my flutter app in order to write tests for my graphql mutations without it actually doing a database read. The way Mockito works is that i set a "when" clause which makes it so whenever that particular method is called on my mocker it uses what I defined instead of what would run normally.

I've defined a when for my mocked GraphQLClient for client.mutate(). however, when I call mutate it says that there is no mock defined. I've done research online and several people fixed the issue by making sure they define the when first, which I have done, but it still hasn't solved my issue. Here is my initialization and packages

```
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

import 'package:graphql/client.dart' as graphql;
import 'login_screen_test.mocks.dart';

@GenerateMocks([graphql.GraphQLClient])
```

and the client and mutation

```
  final mockClient = MockGraphQLClient();
  MutationOptions loginMutation = MutationOptions(
    document: gql(
      r'''
        mutation Login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
          login(input: {email:$email password:$password}) {
            accessToken
            refreshToken
            user {
              id
            }
          }
        }
      ''',
    ),
    variables: <String, dynamic>{
      'email': 'doodle@noodle.com',
      'password': 'password',
    },
  );
```

and now the test case

```
  test('Login success if done correctly', () async {
    when(mockClient.mutate(loginMutation)).thenAnswer((_) async => graphql.QueryResult(source: null, data: {'login': {'accessToken': 'ooglyboogly', 'refreshToken': 'mtnDew'}}));
    await userRepo.loginEmailPassword(mockClient, email: 'doodle@noodle.com', password: 'password');
    expect(store.state.auth.accessToken, isNot(''));
  });
```

Here is the mutation being called in the userRepo

```
  Future<bool> loginEmailPassword({required String email, required String password, mockClient = ''}) async {
    final MutationOptions options = MutationOptions(
      document: gql(
        r'''
          mutation Login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
            login(input: {email:$email password:$password}) {
              accessToken
              refreshToken
              user {
                id
              }
            }
          }
        ''',
      ),
      variables: <String, dynamic>{
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
      },
    );
    QueryResult result = mockClient == '' ? await client.mutate(options) : await mockClient.mutate(options);
    if (result.hasException) {
      throw Exception(result.exception);
    }
    store.dispatch(Login(accessToken: result.data!['login']['accessToken'],refreshToken: result.data!['login']['refreshToken']));
    return true;
  }
```

Another thing is that i see the mutate method in the mock file that is generated

```
  @override
  _i5.Future<_i2.QueryResult> mutate(_i2.MutationOptions? options) =>
      (super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#mutate, [options]),
              returnValue: Future<_i2.QueryResult>.value(_FakeQueryResult_5()))
          as _i5.Future<_i2.QueryResult>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mocks file is generated. The file name should be something like that: 'your_test_file_name.mocks.dart'

if you can't find the generated mocks file try running

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Comment: good idea, My mock file is generated though :/ And in that file there is a mutate function

Comment: I'm going to add more details to the original question